# Angular - async comunication between components

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, settimeout

Have situation when all my components initialize asynchronously. But what i need is, when comp. n.1 gets initialized affects immediately comp. n.2 . So I have this code now.

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        if (this.params?.filterCmpSyscode) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                this._loadFilterCmp(this.params?.filterCmpSyscode);
            }, 1500);
        }
    }


    protected _loadFilterCmp(syscode: string) {
        const cmp = this.appService.getComponentBySyscode(syscode);
        this.filterCmp = cmp;
    }
```

As you see, it works through the appService communication, but I have to have this delay to be sure, its has been already loaded.

I would like to get rid of the `setTimeout`. So anyone has/had similar issue and know the way around?

EDIT to reply to comments:
getComponentBySyscode = (syscode: string): Configurable => this._components[syscode]
this is the function and no, it is not async.
Whole procejt is actualy a big web aplication, so it would be diffincult to take just part and make a working stackbliz example.
To get you some more details. Every page is actually a aplication full of components working on their own, thgough pageConfig and app service, etc. Before we never needed to make componetnt trully communicate. But what i do need now is, that when 2 components are initialized, 1st has to inmidiately affect the other, so the 2nd does not load as usually(with its own setting), but uses data from 2nd component.
1st is product filter, 2nd is product list thats display list of filtered products.

Comment: your question needs to be explained properly, what does the service even do? can you provide a working example on stackblitz, also expected output with screenshots!

Comment: `getComponentBySyscode` is that an async function? Please show this function.

Comment: Add a subject in your service, then, when load data, make a "emit", then subscribe to the subject in the other component